# Accessing App Keychain Data on Non-Jailbroken (iOS) or Non-Rooted (Android) Devices

Tags: android, ios, react-native, jailbreak

I'm working on an app that handles sensitive user data, and I'm interested in understanding the security implications around accessing an app's keychain data on non-jailbroken (iOS) or non-rooted (Android) devices. My understanding is that keychain data is secure and isolated from other apps.
Is it true that keychain data is completely secure on non-jailbroken/non-rooted devices?
I have read that both iOS and Android have strong security measures in place, but I'm wondering if there are any known scenarios where keychain data might be compromised.

Comment: In general, to access the keychain data an attacker would need to physically posses the device and know the device passcode. Someone with this access is effectively the device owner. It makes no sense to try and secure data from the owner themselves. Of course it is in theory possible that a very sophisticated state actor may have access to zero day exploits that allow remote compromise but that is a very limited risk for the vast majority of users.